# "Generate entities from table" (MS Access) in Eclipse via UCanAccess

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, jpa, ucanaccess

I created a JPA project to use the tool *Generate entities from Table* to create an Entitie from a big big! MS Access Database Table.

I'm trying to use UCanAccess as JDBC Driver:
[image: connection profile configuration 1]
[image: connection profile configuration 2]

But when I test the connection I get this error:
[image: test connection error]

**Somebody knows what can I try to make it works?**

**Is there any other good tool to generate entities from table?**

I have created a simple class to test UCanAccess and my database and everything works right.

Comment: I don't know about *UCanAccess*, but if you're using a Java version before 1.7 you can just use the JDBC/ODBC bridge. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GDj3NTSAtMU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is something bad in  your JDBC URL, e.g.:

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Public/Database1.accdb;showSchema=true
```

Notice that the IDE can't know how the JDBC URL should be composed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed someone would construct the complete URL with the specified data. That's where I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me:

[image: NewDriver.png]

[image: NewConnectionProfile.png]

Comment: Yes because you do it in the right way, not like me. The difference is in the connection URL. Just like @jamadei says.